# Proper way to inherit base class constructor using type aliases?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, using

I'm trying to inherit constructor of a template base class with a very lengthy name.
For this base class I introduced type alias. (https://godbolt.org/z/aqf6czPdo)

```cpp
class Object {};
class Gadget {};

class SuperBase : public Object { using base_t = Object; };
class Params : public Gadget { using base_t = Gadget; };

template<class T, class TParams>
class Base : public SuperBase, public TParams {};

template<class T>
class Derived : public Base<T, Params>
{
    using base_t = Base<T, Params>;
public:
    using base_t::base_t;
};
```

This code compiles successfully using GCC and Clang, but does not compile with MSVC `/permissive-` flag with

```
error C2385: ambiguous access of 'base_t'
note: could be the 'base_t' in base 'SuperBase'
note: or could be the 'base_t' in base 'Params'
```

If I write it like `using base_t::Base;`, then MSVC compiles successfully, but clang fails. Using full base class name `using Base<T, Params>::Base;` works for all three compilers.

The question is what compiler is correct in this case?

I've expected that all three compilers would compile this code successfully. Many answers on stackoverflow suggest that type aliases can in fact be used to inherit base class constructors.

Comment: Well this is fascinating.  It appears that MSVC is interpreting `using base_t::base_t` as the `base_t` alias within the `base_t` alias, instead of as the inheriting constructor :O. I would assume that's an error.

Comment: I wasnt sure which tag to remove, but I think the `language-lawyer` tag is appropriate. Note that `language-lawyer` questions are treated a little different. Its assumed that you want answers to point to the relevant parts in the standard rather than saying "yes" or "no" with an explanation. Rollback if thats not your intention

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that's fine. I remember there's a special note about using alias names in constructor _declaration_, but nothing about inheriting.

Comment: I think the standard isn't exactly a wonder of clarity regarding this. (It doesn't help matters that it manages to mention "a qualified-id that names a constructor" and say "constructors do not have names" in the same paragraph.)

Comment: You're not letting us escape with that one. If you weren't using CRTP, I'd make `base` the last  template argument, and give the long name as default aliase. But that cannot be done with CRTP.

Comment: It seems that there nothing in specs clarifying that case.
What I see : in using base_t::base_t the first base_t is clearly the local alias-declaration, but for the second, it is a name preceded by ::, so have to search what is Base<T,Params>::base_t and then the ambiguity seen by MSVC.
For me, MSVC is right. I see nothing in specs saying that this sequence must interpreted as a constructor.

Comment: @dalfaB _I see nothing in specs saying that this sequence must interpreted as a constructor_ What about http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1.sentence-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an MSVC bug: [class.qual]/1.2 (/2.2 in C++20) says clearly that the **same** name appearing on either side of the `::` indicates inheriting constructors.  The current wording restricts this lexical treatment to **dependent** *using-declarator*s ([namespace.udecl]/1), but of course this one is.  (The injected-class-name is the trigger for non-dependent names, since constructors can’t directly be found by name lookup at all.)